# Defining custom type families over the Nat kind

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, data-kinds

How does one define new computation over types of kind `GHC.TypeLits.Nat`? I am hoping to be able to define a type family

```
type family WIDTH (n :: Nat) :: Nat
```

such that `WIDTH 0 ~ 0` and `WIDTH (n+1) ~ log2 n`

Comment: What about `log2 0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can pattern match on any literal `Nat`, then recurse using built-in operations.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

type family Div2 n where
  Div2 0 = 0
  Div2 1 = 0
  Div2 n = Div2 (n - 2) + 1

type family Log2 n where
  Log2 0 = 0  -- there has to be a case, else we get nontermination
              -- or we could return Maybe Nat
  Log2 1 = 0
  Log2 n = Log2 (Div2 n) + 1

type family WIDTH n where
  WIDTH 0 = 0
  WIDTH n = Log2 (n - 1)
```